# How many times will epoll_wait() notify the process when N sockets are connected with a listening socket?

Tags: c, io, epoll

> When successful, epoll_wait(2) returns
>   the number of file descriptors ready
>   for the requested I/O, or zero  if  no
>   file descriptor  became  ready during
>   the requested timeout milliseconds. 
>   When an error occurs, epoll_wait(2)
>   returns -1 and errno is set
>   appropriately.

Suppose the epoll is ET triggered,will `epoll_wait` notify the process N times for N connected sockets or only once?

Comment: To my knowledge it'll only trigger once and notify you how many sockets are ready for read and/or write ops.

Comment: @Kevin,`epoll_wait` only returns the number of listening fd that's ready for IO,not how many sockets connected.

Comment: @compile-fan Sorry, I forgot `e_poll` is also for files. Maybe you should add something like 'io' or 'file' as a tag?

Comment: In edge-triggered mode, epoll will give you _one_ event for every socket that becomes ready, _once_ per socket _since the last call to either_ `epoll_wait` _or_ `read` _in any thread_. Be sure to carefully read the "smallprint", it is an important detail and very different from what the documentation says. That means if you have 10 sockets, 5 of them receive data (of which one receives 3 network packets), you get 5 events in epoll (not 8!). If you have a socket that receives 10 messages and 3 threads are in epoll_wait, then only _one_ will wake up (unlike in LT mode, and unlike the docs).

Comment: @compile-fan: Sadly, epoll does not work the same way as kqueue. Adding ordinary file descriptors to an epoll will fail with EPERM (though when using kernel AIO, you _can_ add an `eventfd` that is signalled upon completion -- this reverts the proactor logic into reactor, however).

Answer (score 0):

If N clients connect at the same time and you accept all of them, further notifications will happen.. if N clients connect and you accept N-1 no notifications will happen until you consume all events..

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose the epoll is ET triggered,will epoll_wait notify the process N times for N connected sockets or > only once?

You will get one notification per socket that has an IO event you asked for. Ofcourse, epoll_wait can deliver more than one notification per call.